# Connect to an LDAP database from C# and return an array

Tags: c#, php, .net, ldap

Basically I want to connect to an LDAP database from C# .Net and return an array of objects.

We have a third party piece of software which is successfully doing this in PHP, the PHP code is below:

```
$ds = @ldap_connect("127.0.0.1",4000)
@ldap_bind($ds,"XXXXX","88888")
$sr=@ldap_list($ds,"cn=Registrations","objectclass=RegistrationRecord",$att);
$info=@ldap_get_entries($ds,$sr);
```

Where the heck do I start repeating this in C#? I'm not even looking for a full solution, just a nudge in the right direction from somebody would help massively as I am lost!

Thanks

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Directory Entry` or `LdapConnection Class`:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://127.0.0.1","admin","password",AuthenticationTypes.None);
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
var findAll = ds.FindAll();
```

Sources:

[Connecting to LDAP from C# using DirectoryServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437250/connecting-to-ldap-from-c-sharp-using-directoryservices)

[LDAP Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.aspx)

[Connecting to an LDAP Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257181%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)