# Active Directory search from wcf and asmx services failing

Tags: c#, wcf, active-directory, ldap, asmx

I have a simple setup below to search for users.

```
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someserver:123/OU=d-users,DC=domain,DC=x,DC=y,DC=com");

rootEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
string filter = "sAMAccountName=" + AccountName;
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry, filter);
SearchResult foundUser = searcher.FindOne();
```

For some reason I can search via a simple Console/windows forms app but cannot search from a wcf or asmx service (v4.0, Integrated) on IIS(6.1). The exception is below;

```
exception:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007200A): The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
   at Tester.FindAccountByName(String AccountName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your filter into brackets:

```
string filter = string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", AccountName);
```

See the [relevant TechNet article on LDAP filter syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details

Comment: made the filter like (sAMAccountName=jon.snow) but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an DirectorySearcher, something like this:

```
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someserver:123/OU=d-users,DC=domain,DC=x,DC=y,DC=com")))
                {
                    StringBuilder filterStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    // Just create a single LDAP query for all user SIDs
                    filterStringBuilder.Append("(&(objectClass=user)(|");
                    filterStringBuilder.AppendFormat("({0}={1})", "sAMAccountName", AccountName);
                    filterStringBuilder.Append("))");
                    searcher.PageSize = 1000; // Very important to have it here. Otherwise you'll get only 1000 at all. Please refere to DirectorySearcher documentation

                    searcher.Filter = filterStringBuilder.ToString();
                    searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.None;

                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(
                        new[] { "DistinguishedName" });

                    var result = searcher.FindOne();
                 }
```

More examples on how to use the DirectorySearcher you can find on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180885%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437250/connecting-to-ldap-from-c-sharp-using-directoryservices)

Comment: Added {AuthenticationType=AuthenticationTypes.None } for user errors. Also getting, "Additional information: The value for the property PageSize cannot be set." error. But when I remove the PageSize setting, I get null from FindOne().

Comment: remove the filtering (filterStringBuilder) and the PropertiesToLoad then try searcher.FindAll() and see what's returning

Comment: with or without PropertiesToLoad, I get 2000 member innerList, but with PropertiesToLoad, additionally I get 2 properties "ADsPath" and "DistinguishedName".